# why are complex null types used in c?

Tags: c

I'm working through some example code from [Understanding Unix/Linux Programming (Bruce Molay)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-UNIX-LINUX-Programming-Practice/dp/0130083968) and I've seen a definition for a NULL utmp type:

```
 #define NULLUT  ((struct utmp *)NULL)
```

This null type used in methods such as:

```
 struct utmp *utmp_next()
 {
    ...
    if (no_more_records)
        return NULLUT;
 }
```

And the client code checks for the NULL utmp as such:

```
 int main()
 {
    ...
    while (( utbufp = utmp_next() ) != ((struct utmp *)NULL) )
       do_something()
 }
```

Why not have utmp_next() just return `NULL` from this method as defined in `stddef.h` and the while loop check for that instead?

The actual book source files are here:

- http://sites.harvard.edu/~lib215/reference/bookcode/code/ch02/utmplib.c
- http://sites.harvard.edu/~lib215/reference/bookcode/code/ch02/who3.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part, they're not. Most C programmers simply use the `NULL` macro, with a cast to the required pointer type only in the rare cases where it's necessary.

By defining a type-specific null pointer macro like

```
#define NULLUT  ((struct utmp *)NULL)
```

you get something that is only of that specific pointer type. Comparing a pointer of a different type, for example:

```
char *ptr = some_value;
if (ptr == NULLUT) /* ERROR */
```

the compiler will flag an error. A null pointer constant, on the other hand, is comparison-compatible with any pointer type.

I suppose the author thought that would be a good idea.

I disagree.

The macro `NULL` is standard, and every C programmer recognizes it. It's perfectly safe to use in a comparison, assignment, initialization, or `return` statement for any pointer type. And most of the time, it's perfectly safe to use as an argument to a function with a pointer parameter. The only exceptions are when the function has no visible prototype (solution: always use prototypes) or when it's a variadic function like `printf` (solution: cast `NULL` to the appropriate pointer type). (Macros using the new `_Generic` feature are probably another case where a cast might be needed.)

Defining your own `NULLUT` macro serves no real purpose that I can see.

```
while (( utbufp = utmp_next() ) != ((struct utmp *)NULL) )
   do_something()
```

This is from another source file from the book (the `who3.c` you cited in the question). Here, the author doesn't even define the `NULLUT` macro, choosing instead to write

```
((struct utmp *)NULL)
```

This would be better written as:

```
while (( utbufp = utmp_next() ) != NULL) )
   do_something()
```

Comment: ...or maybe the author self-defined `NULL` earlier as `(void*)0` and used the conversion stuff above to make it work with C++ compilers... =P

Comment: @Mints97: Yes, there are a number of possible *really bad* reasons to do that.

Comment: The `void main()` was my typo :(   I have updated that.  I have also attached a link to the source files.

Comment: Even using `NULL` is often not such a good idea, it is one of the points where the C standard is really failing. In most cases using `0` is completely sufficient and it is exactly the same on all platforms.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I disagree. Using `NULL` makes it clear that it's a null pointer. Sure, you *could* use `0` rather than `NULL`, `0.0`, and `'\0'`, but personally I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: The problem with `NULL` is that its contents is implementation defined, so you think that it is explicit where it isn't: https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/dont-use-null/

Comment: @JensGustedt: I read your article, and I still strongly disagree. The expansion of `NULL` is absolutely guaranteed to be a null pointer constant. However it's defined, it's perfectly safe to use in an assignment, initialization, `return` statement, or comparison with something of pointer type. The only exceptions are passing a parameter to a function with no prototype or to a variadic function. For those cases, just use `(type*)NULL`. (And there's no good reason to use non-prototyped functions anyway.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, since C11 types are observable through `_Generic`. If your "function" turns out to be a macro that does a type generic choice, you get the `int` function, the `long` function the `void*` one, according to the mood of your compiler implementor. But even without `_Generic`, tell me what type `1 ? NULL :  (struct toto*)1` is? Macros that have a hidden implementation defined type are just bad. C++ has invented `nullptr` for this.

Comment: @JensGustedt: `_Generic` is another case where it might matter. As for `1 ? NULL : (struct toto*)1` -- just don't do that.